Please help me solving probability question
Click here to check actual questionPlease Clear my doubt..given answer in book is 1/26 and some online sites has 2/51 but I think both are wrong
Question is - Two card are drawn at random from pack of 52 card.Probablity of getting at least a spade and an ace is??
I'm confused that there should be two case or not ..one case if ace of spade drawn then 2nd card is independent?

Have you quoted the exact question  word by word ? This is essential to know before coming to any conclusion

Clarification: Two cards are drawn - with or without replacement? Meaning, is the first card put back to the deck before the second card is drawn? I'm asking because this changes the probability.

I've added actual picture of question from my book

Please make your question self-contained by including the question in the text of your post.  Please transcribe equations and text using Mathjax.  Don't use pictures of text/mathematics; that is not accessible to those with visual impairments, and prevents finding this page via search.

I encourage you to [edit] your post to provide a more descriptive title.  Also, I encourage you to provide some context or motivation.  In what context did this question arise?  What is the motivation for it?  Why do you anticipate this will be useful to others in the future?  This site is designed as a way for people to collaborate in building an archive of knowledge that will be useful for others in the future, so we're looking for questions that will be useful not just to you but to others as well.  Please provide a proper reference for the book (title, authors, section, exercise number).

"..at least a spade an an ace..."
The two distinct possibilities that fit the criteria,
splitting according to the type of ace are

ace of spades, any other
non-spade ace, non-ace spade

Then $Pr = \dfrac{1\cdot51 + 3\cdot12 }{\binom{52}2}= \large\frac{29}{442}$
